# Improving sound latencies for video presentation in python

Tags: python, audio, video, latency, psychopy

I am creating an experiment in python. It includes the presentation of many mp4 videos, that include both image and sound. The sound is timed so that it appears at the exact same time as a certain visual image in the video. For the presentation of videos, I am using psychopy, namely the visual.MovieStim3 function.

Because I do not know much about technical sound issues, I am not sure if I should/can take measures to improve possible latencies. I know that different sound settings make a difference for the presentation for sound stimuli alone in python, but is this also the case, if the sound is embedded in the video? And if so, can I improve this by choosing a different sound library?

Thank you for any input.
Juliane

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely be using a PsychoPy release > 3.2:

https://github.com/psychopy/psychopy/releases

Release 3.2 included audio code ported by Mario Kleiner from the Psyctoolbox project. This leads to audio timing that is far superior to previous performance, which was inconsistent across platforms and different audio backends. Here is a graph showing the latency relative to a parallel port pulse, with gridlines representing 1 ms:

[image]

This is explained by Jon Peirce in [this post](https://discourse.psychopy.org/t/new-release-3-2-0/8931/2?u=michael) as

> here’s a pretty picture of the new audio lib in a few repetitions of a sound under Win10 with standard built-in audio hardware. The yellow trace(s) represent a simple tone, the cyan trace is a labjack trigger. Note that the gridlines represent 1ms.
>
> To get this precision you do need to pre-schedule the sound using snd.play(when)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You are right, I meant to impove the synchroation of image material and sound material WITHIN the video. However, I am not even sure, if I can influence that within the python code. 
Unfortunately, at the moment, I cannot simply switch to PsychyPy3 (time and organizational reasons).

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, yes, the issues are the same for audio-visual sync whether or not they are embedded in a movie file. By the time the computer plays them they are simply visual images on a graphics card and an audio stream on a sound card. The streams just happen to be bundled into a single (mp4) file.

Comment: Thank you for the info, Jon. Do you know, if there is a specific sound environment that works best with MovieStim3?